# can Dictionary<string, HtmlTable> be used together in C#?

Tags: c#

Hi guys I am very new to C#, I am an intern currently doing a project for my company. I came across this which I don't really understand.
Can `Dictionary<string, HtmlTable> tableTracker = new Dictionary <string, HtmlTable>();` be used together? because I am trying to save my data into my database but when I run line by line it skips the line which leads to the definition above. Sorry if I did not provide enough information, I will try to provide it from your feedback. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just try it out?What do you mean by "can they be used together"? Syntactically there's nothing hindering you from doing that.

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't be valid. Dictionary is just that, a dictionary associating one thing with another thing. 
That snippet, in particular, creates a new dictionary with string keys and HtmlTable values (and assigns it to a variable). 
It's impossible to say more without context (i.e., surrounding code).

Comment: Yes, @SpaceBeeGaming. I still don't understand why it does not run but after I added a static in front of Dictionary, it starts to run this line.

Comment: It does not give me any error, @HimBromBeere. But it just skips passed this line when I am trying to debug it line by line which I don't really understand why

Comment: Could you provide a little more code to show what is happening immediately before and after that line? Also: Are you changing the code *while* debugging (as opposed to stopping and restarting the debug session?). That might perhaps explain why it would appear to be skipping that line, since not all changes might get "picked up" in the middle of a session.